# How to display image in canvas in angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, canvas

I have an image  i am getting from a url. I want to display this image in a canvas but when it gives me error image not found but my image is present in a folder and I have given its path correclty. Tell me why it is saying image not found?

I have this in Html:

```
 <canvas #canvas></canvas>
```

Here is my component Code:

```
export class drawingTestFormComponent{
@Input() public width = 495;
@Input() public height = 445;

private cx: CanvasRenderingContext2D;

public ngAfterViewInit() {
    const canvasEl: HTMLCanvasElement = this.canvas.nativeElement;
    this.cx = canvasEl.getContext('2d')!;
    let image = new Image();


    canvasEl.width = this.width;
    canvasEl.height = this.height;

    this.cx.lineWidth = 3;
    this.cx.lineCap = 'round';
    this.cx.strokeStyle = '#000';
    image.onload = ()=> {
        this.cx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this.width, this.height);
    }
    image.src = "../../../../wwwroot/dist/assets/blackBoards/NCAA_mhalfcourt_500x410.png";

}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks good the only issue I have found is that you have not defined the canvas variable.

```
@ViewChild("canvas") canvas;
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-smyy4j?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: I have defined canvas variable i-e   { @ViewChild('canvas') public canvas: ElementRef } but this is not working in my case. And also this demo is not working as well.

Comment: @MuhammadNaeemAkhtar : I just verified demo is working.please verify again

Comment: I change the image source now its working fine. Thanks

Comment: Link broken: "ikes! The page you requested couldn't be found." :/